# Cloudformation CLI Parameters Using Deploy Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm having an issue getting the hang of using cli parameters with `cloudformation deploy`.  I'm trying to pass in the name for the S3 bucket that I want to create, and the cli is complaining when I use `--parameters` to do this:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ../infrastructure.yml --stack-name stripe-python --parameters ParameterKey=S3BucketNameParameter,ParameterValue=lambda-artifacts-948d01bc80800b36
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

push                                     | register                                
deregister                               | install
```

Obviously, omitting the parameter doesn't work either:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ../infrastructure.yml --stack-name stripe-python 

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [S3BucketNameParameter] must have values
```

When I look at [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) for `cloudformation deploy`, it seems to not support `--parameters` but instead `--parameter-overrides`, which I've also tried with no success:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file ../infrastructure.yml --stack-name stripe-python --parameter-overrides S3BucketNameParameter=lambda-artifacts-948d01bc80800b36

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [S3BucketNameParameter] must have values
```

So, I'm kind of stumped here.  Here's the template file's contents:

```
cat ../infrastructure.yml 
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Lambda application that calls the Stripe API to tokenize and charge credit cards
Parameters: 
  S3BucketNameParameter: 
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket name for deployment artifacts
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref S3BucketNameParameter
```

Any suggestions on the correct approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file infrastructure.yml --stack-name stripe-python --parameter-overrides S3BucketNameParameter=lambda-artifacts-948d01bc80800b36
```

It may come down to awscli version (ie check the version you are running and the doc for that)

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.44 Python/3.8.5 Darwin/18.7.0 source/x86_64
```